# emplace_back and Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, c++11

I am wondering if you can store items into a vector, using the emplace_back, a type that is derived from the class that vector expects.

For example:

```
struct fruit
{
    std::string name;
    std::string color;
};

struct apple : fruit
{
    apple() : fruit("Apple", "Red") { }
};
```

Somewhere else:

```
std::vector<fruit> fruits;
```

I want to store an object of type apple inside the vector. Is this possible?

Comment: Your forgot your semicolons there, skippy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. A vector only stores elements of a fixed type. You want a pointer to an object:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<fruit>> fruit_vector;

fruit_vector fruits;
fruits.emplace_back(new apple);
fruits.emplace_back(new lemon);
fruits.emplace_back(new berry);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have a small question though, say I create a local unique_ptr to store the object from the fruit_vector, wouldn't the memory at the address be deleted when that local unique_ptr goes out of scope?

Comment: @TheAJ: Well, that's the whole point, right? If you want to keep the object, transfer the pointer to the container...

Comment: More elegant way in C++14 would be: `fruits.emplace_back(std::make_unique<apple>());`

Comment: @MaciejS: No, you'd use `push_back` in that case.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089227/push-back-or-emplace-back-with-stdmake-unique

Comment: @MaciejS: Use push_back when it works, and emplace_back when you have to. The purpose of emplace is to use explicit constructors, and if you don't have to do that, you can use a more appropriate tool.

Comment: @MaciejS: Basically, if you already have an object of the right type, use push_back. If you want to *construct* an object from constructor arguments,  use emplacement.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, but this isn't the only benefit to using `emplace_back()` it also returns a reference to the newly created element, which is a reason to prefer the method suggested by @MaciejS

Comment: @JamieBullock: Not in C++11 (see question tag) :-)

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<fruit> fruits;`
It only stores fruit in fruits not derived types as allocator only allocates `sizeof(fruit)` for each element. To keep polymorphism, you need to store pointer in fruits.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<fruit>> fruits;
fruits.emplace_back(new apple);
```

apple is dynamically allocated on free store, will be release when element is erased from vector.

```
fruits.erase(fruits.begin());
```