# push_back or emplace_back with std::make_unique

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, c++14, unique-ptr

Based on the answers in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783342/should-i-use-c11-emplace-back-with-pointers-containters) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172888/is-it-safe-to-use-emplace-back-with-a-container-of-unique-ptrs) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303513/push-back-vs-emplace-back?rq=1), I know that it is certainly preferred to use c++14's `std::make_unique` than to `emplace_back(new X)` directly.

That said, is it preferred to call

```
my_vector.push_back(std::make_unique<Foo>("constructor", "args"));
```

or

```
my_vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>("constructor", "args"));
```

That is, should I use `push_back` or `emplace_back` when adding an `std::unique_ptr` constructed from `std::make_unique`?

==== EDIT ====

and why? c: <-- (tiny smile)

Comment: With an actual argument of the vector's item type, `push_back` and `emplace_back` necessarily do the same.

Comment: Related: http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/HowardHinnant/papers/blob/master/insert_vs_emplace.html

Comment: If you have a custom deleter on your `unique_ptr`, then things can change.

Comment: Regarding @dyp's link, I ran that code on VS2022 and insert and emplace were identical in each case.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't make a difference as far as construction of the new object is concerned; you already have a `unique_ptr<Foo>` prvalue (the result of the call to `make_unique`) so both `push_back` and `emplace_back` will call the `unique_ptr` move constructor when constructing the element to be appended to the `vector`.

If your use case involves accessing the newly constructed element after insertion, then `emplace_back` is more convenient since C++17 because it returns a reference to the element. So instead of

```
my_vector.push_back(std::make_unique<Foo>("constructor", "args"));
my_vector.back().do_stuff();
```

you can write

```
my_vector.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Foo>("constructor", "args")).do_stuff();
```

Comment: Yes agreed, that's why I asked. :)

Comment: Actually, there is a difference... `emplace_back()` returns a reference to the added element, whereas `push_back()` returns void. `emplace_back(std::make_unique<>())` is therefore useful in contexts where you need to use the object after it has been added.

Comment: @JamieBullock Well, there was no difference when I answered the question 3 years ago. Updated the answer to include the C++17 change to the return type. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly

```
template<class T, class A, class...Args>
void push_unique( std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>,A>& v, Args&&...args ) {
  v.push_back( std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) );
}
```

is the best option:

```
push_unique(my_vector,"constructor", "args");
```

sadly this is prefix notation: (operator, container, arguments...) vs infix (container operator arguments...).

If only there was a way to make it infix, like [extension methods](http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2014/10/15/extension-methods-in-cpp/) or [named operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090751/1774667).

Because that would be cool.