# Are raw pointers automatically converted to smart pointers when emplaced and pushed to a vector of smart pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I just stumbled upon a code like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit>> fruits;
fruits.emplace_back(new Fruit);
```

([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420833/9259778))

So in the code we have a raw pointer (`new` produces a raw pointer, right?) pushed into a vector of unique pointers. And the code works! But why?

Because this does not compile:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Fruit> f = new Fruit();
```

Is it a bit of under-the-hood magic, for convenience?

Also, what are the possible pitfalls of this approach instead of explicit `fruits.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Fruit>())`? I've read that `make_unique` is the preferred method of creating unique pointers.

Comment: Note that the call to `emplace_back` has a bug: if an exception is thrown by `emplace_back` (you run out of memory), you leak the `new Fruit`.

Comment: @Justin Do you mean in general, or in this exact case?

Comment: This case. In general, if you allocate a resource in a call to `emplace_back`, expecting the resource to be owned by the created element in `std::vector`, if allocation fails, you will leak the resource.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Fruit> f(new Fruit());` does compile though and is equivalent to what `emplace_back` does

Comment: @Justin Ah, I think I got it, so the vector wouldn't be able to deallocate the allocated `Fruit`.

Comment: @UnholySheep By the way, yes. So this is a little magic for our convenience, right

Comment: I wouldn't call it magic, it's simply the only sensible way of implementing the `emplace_back` function.

Comment: @UnholySheep Yeah the answerers showed that this is not magic, but passing the value to underlying constructor of `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And the code works! But why?

`vector::emplace_back` takes a list of arguments, and just forwards them to the constructor of the element that it creates.

`unique_ptr<Fruit>::unique_ptr(Fruit*)` is a constructor that takes ownership of the passed bare pointer.

> Also, what are the possible pitfalls of this approach instead of [`make_unique`]

The big pitfall is that `emplace_back` may throw an exception, in which case no `unique_ptr` has been successfully created. In such case, the allocated object passed to `emplace_back()` would be leaked. Therefore, passing a `unique_ptr` rather than a bare pointer is preferable so the raw pointer is always owned by someone.

<sub>Minor point regarding the use of `new` instead of `std::make_unique()` in general: It leaves the program "imbalanced" in a way that prevents you from reasoning about the correctness of the program using the age old rule of thumb "`delete` exactly as many pointers as you `new`". In this case, you have a correct program with more `new` than `delete`. Whether this is an issue is matter of personal opinion.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if `make_unique` should still be preferred?

Comment: This use of `new` is correct except for the corner case of `vector.emplace_back` throwing due to lack of memory. In that case, the `new Fruit` leaks.

Comment: @Justin oh, right. That's very important. Added to the answer.

Comment: "*In this case, you have a correct program with more `new` than `delete`*" - but you don't, really. The `delete` is merely hidden inside the `unique_ptr` that `std::make_pointer()` returns, but it still exists nonetheless.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `The delete is merely hidden inside the unique_ptr` That's exactly the point. It is not in **your** code. It is hidden within somebody elses code.

Comment: @eerorika Not any different than any other kind of smart pointer (`bstr_t`, `_com_ptr_t`, etc) that takes a pre-allocated memory as input and releases it for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed. They also share the same problems unless paired with an analogous `make_X` function.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::unique_ptr<Fruit> f = new Fruit();
```

doesn't work but

```
std::unique_ptr<Fruit> f{new Fruit()};
```

works. The first one does not work because, syntactically, it uses [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). Copy intialization does not work for `std::unique_ptr` since the constructor that accepts a pointer as argument is `explicit`.

```
fruits.emplace_back(new Fruit);
```

works because of the presence of the constructor used above.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if I `make_unique` should still be preferred over this shorted version?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev, I would personally prefer to use `make_unique` instead of `new Fruit`. It removes `new`/`delete` imbalance in your own code. Other people may prefer use of `new Fruit` for reasons that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Thank you! I've already decided to choose `make_unique`, you have strengthen my decision.

Comment: The assignment is not working because the constructor that takes a pointer is marked explicit, not because there is no copy constructor.